# Plotting two numeric columns in pandas in same graph with dates on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

[image: Currently I have this graph:]

From this code:
    data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
    data.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)

```
data['mean_Kincaid'] = data.Kincaid.rolling(250, 
min_periods=1).mean()
data.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Kincaid',  
legend=False, title="Kincaid scores over time")
```

Using this line:

```
data['mean_Score'] = data.Score.rolling(250, min_periods=1).mean()
```

I would like to plot the 'mean_Score' on the same graph preferably with a dotted line. My attempt:

```
data.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Kincaid', y = 'mean_Score',  legend=False, 
title="Kincaid scores over time")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get the axes handle from the first plot then use the `ax` paramater in pandas.DataFrame.plot to plot second line on same axes:

```
ax = data.plot(x='Data', y='mean_Kincaid',legend=False, title="Kincaid score over time")
data.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Score', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I ran the code it returned the location of an object (<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x10d4da978>) but did not actually produce a plot -- is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Import Matplotlib.pyplot then add plt.show() to your code

Comment: Running that I get: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt'